# Load a NSURL from a JSON file swift and link it to an imageView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimageview, nsurl

I am trying to get a "path" which is a URL from a JSON file and link it to a imageView in my project. The image and the path come in one JSON line like this

```
{image:"http//www.something.com", path:"http://www.godbsdahb.com" }
```

I managed to download and fill in a scrollview with the images but now I want to click on the images and then redirect to another URL. I manage the redirection, but not the linking of the path to the image. I am lost in how to do that.

Here is what I have so far and it works too but there is no link to the path and the image:

```
    var numOfPromo = 0;

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func loadPromo() {
    numOfPromo = 0;
    PromoMan.sharedInstance.getAllPromoFromServer({
        promotions in
        for (_,promotion) in promotions {
            self.downloadImage(NSURL(string: promotion.picture)!)
            //The path for the promo is promotion.path
        }},
        onFail: { error_code, detail in Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: "Get All Promotions Fail, error_code: \(error_code), detail: \(detail)",
            function: "viewDidLoad")})
}

//Add paths to the promtion images
func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}

func downloadImage(url: NSURL){
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PromotionViewController.imageTapped))
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data));
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                y: Int(self.numOfPromo * 230), width: Int(self.pScrollView.frame.size.width), height: 200)
            self.pScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.numOfPromo = self.numOfPromo + 1;
            
            //Make sure the images will all fit into the scrollview
        
            self.pScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.pScrollView.frame.size.width,
                CGFloat(self.numOfPromo * 230));
        }
    }
}

func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }.resume()
}
```

### Update

Here is the http calls for the images and data

```
 public func getAllPromotionsFromServer(
    onSuccess: (promotions: [String: Promotion])->(),
    onFail: (error_code: APIErrorCode, detail: String)->()){
        
        let url = Config.getBaseUrl() + "/promotions"
    
        Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: "Get All Promotions from Server", function: "getAllPromotionsFromServer")
        
        APIManager.sharedInstance.get(url,params: nil,completion: { response in
            //Change back to global queue
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
                switch response {
                    
                case APIResult.Failure(let error):
                    
                    let msg = "Get Promotions Fail"
                    Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: msg, function: "getAllPromotionsFromServer")
                    
                    let code = Utility.getAPIErrorCode(error)
                    onFail(error_code: code.error_code, detail: code.detail)
                    return
                    
                case APIResult.Success(let response):
                    
                    if response.HTTP_Status == 200
                    {
                        let promotions = APIJSONParser.parsePromotions(response.jsonData)
                        print("Json response")
                        print(response.jsonData)
                        Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: "Get Promotions Success: no. \(promotions.count)", function: "getAllPromotionsFromServer")
                        onSuccess(promotions: promotions)
                        return
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        let code = Utility.getAPIErrorCode(response)
                        onFail(error_code: code.error_code, detail: code.detail)
                        return
                    }
                    
                }
            })
        })
        
}
```

### Update

New Code block:

```
 private func loadPromotions() {
    numberPromotions = 0;
    PromotionManager.sharedInstance.getAllPromotionsFromServer({
        promotions in
        for (_,promotion) in promotions {
            Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: promotion.picture, function: "viewDidLoad")
            
            let p = (picture: promotion.picture, path: promotion.path)
            self.promos.append(p)
            self.downloadImage(NSURL(string: promotion.picture)!, index: self.promos.count)
            //The path for the promo is promotion.path
        }},
        onFail: { error_code, detail in Utility.log(self.dynamicType, msg: "Get All Promotions Fail, error_code: \(error_code), detail: \(detail)",
            function: "viewDidLoad")})
}

//Add paths to the promtion images
func imageTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
            //let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
            //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    if let imageView = gesture as? UIImageView
    {
        if let url = NSURL(string: self.promos[imageView.tag].path)
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
  
    
}

func downloadImage(url: NSURL, index : Int){
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PromotionViewController.imageTapped))
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data));
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.tag = index
            //get images with a space between them 
            //200 = no space
            //230 = black space
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                y: Int(self.numberPromotions * 230), width: Int(self.promotionsScrollView.frame.size.width), height: 200)
            self.promotionsScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.numberPromotions = self.numberPromotions + 1;
            
            //Make sure the images will all fit into the scrollview
        
            self.promotionsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.promotionsScrollView.frame.size.width,
                CGFloat(self.numberPromotions * 230));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the method `imageTapped` is being called?

Comment: Yes it opens a web browser with google as the page when i tap on every image

Comment: What I want is to load in the path url where google webpage is

Comment: So what part of your code is not working? Do you have a hint?

Comment: It is all working. I just don't know how to get the path data and connect it to the respected image

Comment: How are you getting the images? Please show me just that code.

Comment: I posted my http calls as well so that should be all my code

Comment: What do you get in the `promotions` variable? Can you show me so I can see how it's composed?

Comment: Or even better show me this: `response.jsonData`

Comment: Json response
[
  {
    "picture" : "http:\webpage.jpg",
    "path" : "http:\webpage.html",
    "label" : ""
  },
  {
    "picture" : "http:antoherwebpage.jpg",
    "path" : "http:\another webpage/promotion",
    "label" : ""
  },
  {
    "picture" : "http:3rd webpage.png",
    "path" : "http:\/\/www.3rd webpage-offer.html",
    "label" : ""
  }

]

Comment: I truncated it so its easer to read but there are full http url link

Comment: Please use `self.downloadImage(NSURL(string: promotion.picture)!, index: self.promos.count - 1)` instead (`self.promos.count - 1`), remember index are 0-based in Swift, otherwise you will be ignoring first index in de array (0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the `promotions` object (the parsed JSON data), you have there picture and path.

You are already using picture to show the pictures in the scrollview.

Now what you need to do is to tell the gesture recognizer to go to the specific path that belongs to that image. As you have one gesture recognizer for all the images (which is perfect), you need to associate "somehow" the pictures with the paths.

To do this, you can create a variable in the scope of the class, an dictionary for example, where you will save all the promotions with its pictures and paths.

I will use an array of tuples, but you can use any data type you want (dictionary, array, etc).

```
private var promos = Array<(picture: String, path: String)>()
```

Inside you for loop, save the data to the variable just created:

```
for (_, promotion) in promotions {
    let p = (picture: promotion.picture, path: promotion.path)
    self.promos.append(p)
    self.downloadImage(NSURL(string: promotion.picture)!, index: self.promos.count - 1)
}
```

Now you need to tell each `UIImageView` to what index of the `promos` array it belongs, just before adding it to the scrollview (It could be after setting `userInteractionEnabled`:

```
imageView.tag = index
```

And you need to add that `index` as a parameter of the function:

```
func downloadImage(url: NSURL, index: Int) { ... }
```

And now you can access it from the gesture recognizer action:

```
func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView {
        if let url = NSURL(string: self.promos[imageView.tag].path) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest changing `gesture` to `sender` as it would make more sense.

Comment: This one is close very close, but when I click on the images it doesn't go to a new url. I have posted up my new code on top. Thank you

Comment: This is the only warning its giving me Cast from 'UITapGestureRecognizer' to unrelated type 'UIImageView' always fails

Comment: Yes, my mistake. It's `if let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView {`

Comment: I'm glad to help. Please don't forget to change this: `self.downloadImage(NSURL(string: promotion.picture)!, index: self.promos.count - 1)`